# Nullstellensatz where field is not algebraically closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Suppose we have a maximal ideal $M\subseteq K[X_1, \dots, X_n]$, where $K$ is an abitrary field. We denote the zero locus of $M$ (over the algebraic closure!) by $\mathbf V(M)\subseteq \overline K^n$. Let $J\subseteq K[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ be an ideal such that $\mathbf V(J)\subsetneqq \mathbf V(M)$.

> Is it true that $\mathbf V(J)=\emptyset$?

In the case where $K$ is algebraically closed, this would obviously be true. (By applying the Nullstellensatz, we would get $M=\sqrt M\subsetneqq \sqrt J$, thus $\sqrt J=K[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ as $M$ is maximal and therefore $\mathbf V(J)=\mathbf V(\sqrt J) = \emptyset$.)

But what about the general case where $K$ is not algebraically closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p \in V (M)$.
Then $M \subseteq \ker \operatorname{ev}_p$, where $\operatorname{ev}_p : K [X_1, \ldots, X_n] \to \bar{K}$ is evaluation at $p$.
Since $M$ is maximal and $\operatorname{ev}_p$ is not constant $0$, we must in fact have $M = \ker \operatorname{ev}_p$.

On the other hand, since $V (J) \subsetneqq V (M)$, there is some $p$ such that $p \in V (M)$ and $p \notin V (J)$.
For such $p$, we can find $f \in J$ such that $\operatorname{ev}_p (f) \ne 0$, which implies $f \notin M$.
But $J \subseteq I (V (J))$, so $f \in I (V (J))$, and $I (V (J)) \supseteq I (V (M)) = M$, so $I (V (J))$ must be the unit ideal.
Hence, $V (J) = V (I (V (J))) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering whether this is generalizable to the case of non-algebraic sets: i.e. replacing $\mathbf V(J)$ by some arbitrary set $X\subseteq \overline K^n$. Then, the argument of choosing some polynomial $f\in J$ would no longer work. Does the assertion still hold in that case?

Comment: It does not. Consider $K = \mathbb{R}$, $n = 1$, $M = (X^2 + 1)$.

Comment: Thanks, of course! And what if $X$ would actually be an affine variety in $\overline K^n$, i.e. we would have the same situation as in the original post except $J\subseteq\overline K[X_1, \dots, X_n]$? (I think the statement should still be true, although the argument of choosing some $f\in J$ would not be possible in that case.)

Comment: Any finite set of points is a closed subvariety, so the same (counter)example is relevant.

Comment: I think $V (M)$ will be a single orbit under the Galois action, but I'm not sure how to prove this.